# Why is $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|\int_a^xk(x,t)(f(t)-g(t))dt| \le ||f-g|| \sup_{x \in [a,b]} \int_a^x |k(x,t)|dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Why is it true to say that:
$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|\int_a^xk(x,t)(f(t)-g(t))dt| \le ||f-g|| \sup_{x \in [a,b]} \int_a^x |k(x,t)|dt$$

Comment: ||f-g|| must be supremum norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because one has that

$$\left| \int h(s)\,ds \right| \le \int |h(s)|\,ds$$

Apply to your and you get

$$\left| \int k(x,t) (f(t)-g(t))\,dt\right| \le \int |k(x,t)||f(t)-g(t)|\,dt \le \int |k(x,t)|||f-g||_\infty\,dt$$

And being $||f-g||_\infty$ a scalar number you can bring it out the integral and the supremum.